# php convert 12hr to 24hr 12:00:am -> 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a datetime format from a form in this format

```
// $start equals 2014-04-19 12:00:am
// I need to convert to 24hr 2014-04-19 00:00:00

$startconvert = str_replace(':am', '', $start);
$startconverted = date( 'Y-d-m H:i:s', strtotime($startconvert));
echo($startconverted);

//becomes 2014-19-04 12:00:00 which is 12pm
```

Anyone know how to do this? This looks right to me but it ends up being 12pm

Comment: Do you really have a `:` before `am`?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same.  That may be your only issue.  Don't replace the `am` and just replace that last `:` with a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:a', '2014-04-19 12:00:am');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This just takes the date you have and reads it in by its parts using `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. That DateTime object can then be formatted normally.

Comment: its a DateTime object that is recognized.. so there are formatting options available